# How to get frame deflections? CSI-Etabs(API)

Tags: c#

I am trying to get results of frame element from Etabs using C# I success to get frame forces, but when I try to get maximum deflection or displacement of frame element I did not find corresponding method to do that just I can get end displacement.

I need the procedure that I can get the maximum def at mid span or at any point along span.

That's the code to get forces

```
ETABS2016.cOAPI etabsObj = null;

try
{
    var etabsObjO = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("CSI.ETABS.API.ETABSObject");
    etabsObj = (ETABS2016.cOAPI)etabsObjO;
}
catch (Exception ex) { return new List<BarResult>(); }

cSapModel model = etabsObj.SapModel;

int NumberResults = 0;
string[] Obj = null;
double[] ObjSta = null;
string[] Elm = null;
double[] ElmSta = null;
string[] LoadCase = null;
string[] StepType = null;
double[] StepNum = null;
double[] P = null;
double[] V2 = null;
double[] V3 = null;
double[] T = null;
double[] M2 = null;
double[] M3 = null;
model.RespCombo.GetNameList(ref LoadCompNumberNames, ref LoadCompNames);
model.LoadCases.GetNameList(ref LoadCasesNumberNames, ref LoadCasesNames);
model.Results.Setup.DeselectAllCasesAndCombosForOutput();
foreach (var loadname in LoadCasesNames)
{
    model.SetPresentUnits(eUnits.Ton_m_C);
    model.Results.Setup.SetCaseSelectedForOutput(loadname);
    model.Results.FrameForce(FrameName, eItemTypeElm.ObjectElm, ref NumberResults, ref Obj, ref ObjSta, ref Elm, ref ElmSta, ref LoadCase, ref StepType, ref StepNum, ref P, ref V2, ref V3, ref T, ref M2, ref M3);
}
```